# Why illegal forward reference error not shown while using static variable with class name

Tags: java

In the below code while accessing a static variable with class name it doesn't throw a forward reference error but accessing it without class name does.

Why this doesn't happen when accessing with class name?

```
class Test{
    static {
        System.out.println(a); // shows error
        a = 99; // and this line too doesn't give error  
        System.out.println(Test.a); // this line doesn't
    }
    static int a = 10;  
    static{
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your exact error message?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  This code doesn't make any sense.  I posted an answer based on what you have, but this is very smelly code.

Comment: illegal forward reference
 at Test                                                                                                 for the line      System.out.println(a); in first static block

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rules for forward reference is defined in [JLS §8.3.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3):

> Use of class variables whose declarations appear textually after the
>   use is sometimes restricted, even though these class variables are in
>   scope (§6.3). Specifically, it is a compile-time error if all of the
>   following are true:
>
> - The declaration of a class variable in a class or interface C appears
>     textually after a use of the class variable;
> - The use is a simple name in either a class variable initializer of C
>     or a static initializer of C;
> - The use is not on the left hand side of an assignment;
> - C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the use.

So, basically your first `Sysout()`, satisfies all the above 4 conditions, and hence it's a compile time error.

In the 2nd `Sysout()`, you're accessing `a` using it's qualified name, rather than simple name, which as per the above rules is allowed.

Now, the reason for this would be, when you access `Test.a`, the compiler is sure that `Test` class has been loaded and all `static` fields have been initialized, so it can access the field `a`. But while accessing `a` on simple name, the compiler isn't sure that initializer for `a` has already run or not, since it might still be in process of loading the class.

Consider the following process of loading of class:

- When a class is loaded, memory is allocated for all the `static` variables declared in it. At this point, the variable `a` has got its memory allocated (declaration done)
- Then all the `static` initializers run in the order of occurrence.

  - First statement is `Sysout(a);`. `a` hasn't been initialized yet, so you can't access it. (error)
  - Second statement is `a = 99`. Here you're actually initializing the variable `a`. Perfectly fine.
  - Third one is `Sysout(Test.a)` - reasoning for this is already posted above. Compiler knows `Test` is already loaded.
  - Then `static int a = 10` is executed. It re-initializes `a` to `10`. Remember, declaration part is already taken care of in first step.

Comment: @Prasanna Because that is actually initializing the variable. Please read the complete answer, I've written the reason there.

Answer (score 2):

First , let's see what [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3) have to say for illegal forward references.

> ***Use of class variables*** whose declarations appear textually after the
>   use is sometimes restricted, even though these class variables are in
>   scope (§6.3). Specifically, it is a compile-time error if all of the
>   following are true:
>
> The declaration of a class variable in a class or interface C appears
>   textually after a use of the class variable;
>
> The use is a simple name in either a class variable initializer of C
>   or a static initializer of C;
>
> The use is not on the left hand side of an assignment;
>
> C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the use.
>
> ***Use of instance variables*** whose declarations appear textually after
>   the use is sometimes restricted, even though these instance variables
>   are in scope. Specifically, it is a compile-time error if all of the
>   following are true:
>
> The declaration of an instance variable in a class or interface C
>   appears textually after a use of the instance variable;
>
> The use is a simple name in either an instance variable initializer of
>   C or an instance initializer of C;
>
> The use is not on the left hand side of an assignment;
>
> C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the use.

It defines what is a illegal forward reference for each - static and instance variables. However, definition seems to be same for both of them. Since your question asks about static, we will dig deep into this only.

1) See, for a static variable, there is `declaration` and there is `initialization`.

```
 static int a; //only declaration
 static int b = 10; //both declaration and initialization
```

2) Use of class variables whose declarations appear textually after the use is **sometimes** restricted, even though these class variables are in scope.

What does it explains to us ? It says that there are cases when we can use static variables even if we declare them afterwards. And in some cases this wont be allowed. So, what are the cases that this won't be allowed ?

If the following 4 conditions are true at the same time. Else you are free to use it even though you have declared it afterwards.

```
a) The declaration of a class variable in a class or interface C appears textually after a use of the class variable;

b) The use is a simple name in either a class variable initializer of C or a static initializer of C;

c) The use is not on the left hand side of an assignment;

d) C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the use.
```

Well, the `a)` point is simple. It says that you must be looking at these rules only when you want to use a static variable before declaring it else why would you dig up into this JLS.

The `b)` point is that if you use simple name like `boy` [and not class name appended to it like `MyClass.boy` only then you `might` enter the problem of illegal forward reference else you are safe my friend. But just this condition don't qualifies for Illegal forward reference else your `a=99` in you code would have given us error immediately. There are 2 more conditions that HAVE to be true for this error to generate . If the below 2 does not qualify, you are allowed to use it like this.]

The point `c)` is pretty straightforward. Are you not using in left hand side of assignment ? If we look at `a=99` , Nope !! `System.out.println(a)` - This is not even an assignment. Hence no left hand assignment is true.

The point `d)` is also simple. It just tell you which class/Interface C he means in definition.Your C = Test.

Now let's revisit your code. At each line of code, I will comment `True+False+True+false` something like this meaning that for each line what point a), b) , c) ,d) will give to each of line. Okay ?

```
class Test {

    static {
        System.out.println(a); // True + True + True +True ; Illegal forward reference
        a = 99; // True +  True + False +True ; No illegal forward reference
        System.out.println(Test.a); // True + False + True + True No illegal forward reference
    }

    static int a = 10;

    static {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

The next question one may think is now what it will print ? What values will it take if we use before declaring it ?

Now we come to rules of static initialization. Here, we will go according to your code.

When class is loaded and no illegal forward reference is not there , all the static variables have been initialized to default value and are present in memory.

Now, after this static initialization takes place.

```
class Test {

    static {
        System.out.println(Test.a);  // prints 0
        a = 99; // a get 99
        System.out.println(Test.a); // prints 99
    }

    static int a = 10;

    static {
        System.out.println(a); // prints 10
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Class initializers are run at the time that the class is loaded, and you cannot determine when exactly this happens.  Code that runs within a class initializer should only be for things that need to be processed or "initialized" for other static methods (or the class itself) to work properly.

Additionally, you are referencing a variable that has not yet been declared.  In your class initializer (the first static block) you assign `a = 99`, but a has not yet been declared.  If anything you'd want to declare the variable, and then initialize it within the static block.

There is no reason to use class initializers for the type of code you are posting.  This should be a static method if anything.

Here's an example

```
class Test{
    static int a = 10;

    static void doSomething(){
        System.out.println(a);
        a = 99;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Then in main you can call `Test.doSomething();`

Comment: Posting for clarification about the static blocks and static variables and thank you.

Comment: What do you want to know?

Comment: when i assign a value to the static variable 'a' it does not shows a forward reference error but if i print the static variable before declaring it shows a error why?. but it does not show a error when we refer with class name (Test.a).

Comment: Essentially because the variable is declared after the call even though it's still within scope.  Since it threw an error already on the previous line there is no need to keep throwing the same compile time error.  Also, you're making your life more complicated by using constructs in ways that they are not designed, such a class initializers as an automatically called void method.  Don't take this the wrong way, but I think you need to learn more about OOP constructs such as classes & objects, and how the static keyword modifies them before you use things like static blocks like this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the static block

```
static {
    System.out.println(a);
    a = 99;
    System.out.println(Test.a);
}
```

will be executed before `a` is declared.

The line with `Test.a` won't fire any error because the compiler checks and finds static variable `a` declared within class `Test`.

Comment: because at that point in time a is a is initialized with its default value, then the line a=99; assigns 99 to it. If you comment out System.out.println(a); line the output of your program will be 99 then 10. So first it will assign 99 to variable a and print that out, then a will be reinitialized to 10 and will be printed out.

Comment: how the value changes to 10 from 99 as it is a class level variable the assigned value will be in class level scope but not in a block level scope.