# Forward reference error? Why not in while accessing from m1 method?

Tags: java, static, controls

```
class StaticControlFlow {

    static int x = 10;
    static int y ;


    //First Static Block 
    static {

        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
        System.out.println(z);
        System.out.println(a);
        m1();
        System.out.println("static block 1");
    }

    // Main Method
    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("main method");
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
        System.out.println(z);
        System.out.println(a);
        m1();
    }

    // Static method
    public static void m1(){
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
        System.out.println(z);
        System.out.println(a);

        System.out.println("static method m1");

    }

    // Second Static Block 
    static {

        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
        System.out.println(z);
        System.out.println(a);
        m1();
        System.out.println("Second Static Block ");
    }


    static int z = 100;
    static int a ;

}
```

---

Error :-

```
static_control_flow>javac StaticControlFlow.java

StaticControlFlow.java:12: error: illegal forward reference
                System.out.println(z);
                                   ^
StaticControlFlow.java:13: error: illegal forward reference
                System.out.println(a);
                                   ^
StaticControlFlow.java:45: error: illegal forward reference
                System.out.println(z);
                                   ^
StaticControlFlow.java:46: error: illegal forward reference
                System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: Forward reference errors only apply in [specific circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29153929/1553851).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, static variables and blocks are evaluated first, then the compiler does a second run and evaluates the static methods, then it goes to all instance variables, blocks and methods.

This is why it is possible to call all static variables from the `m1()` method

Answer (score 0):

Static blocks are executed as they're defined, and before static fields are initialized.
As you can see you're using

```
static int z = 100;
static int a;
```

inside a static block, before they're correctly initialized.

---

Anyway, accessing those `static` fields calling `m1` inside a `static` block will simply print `0`, as they're not property initialized and default values are used.

Comment: I think OP wants to know why the same static block can reference `z` indirectly, via `m1()`.

Comment: Yes , this is my doubt how this works indirect read of static variable not resulting in forward reference error.

Comment: @Rahul because the compiler assumes that when the `m1` gets called, all the fields are properly initialized. That's by Java Language Specification