# Problem with illegal forward reference in Java

Tags: java

Why when I use reference `this` in a variable declaration, illegal forward reference doesn't appear? What's the difference between declaration with `this` and without it?

The following example fails to compile because of the illegal forward reference:

```
class FailsToCompile {
    int a = b; //illegal forward reference
    int b = 10;
}
```

By qualifying the use of `b` by `this` the compilation error goes away.

```
class Compiles {
    int a = this.b; //that's ok
    int b = 10;
}
```

Comment: Possibly related (although it is about static field) [Why illegal forward reference error not shown while using static variable with class name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29153703)

Comment: @Pshemo I think the mechanics behind it are the same, aren't they? So that should count as a duplicate

Comment: @Lino You are probably right, but since I didn't read that post yet I don't want to use my dupe-hammer based just on probability.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Meaning: **scope** is extremely important here, and your code snippets leave out the scope completely!

Comment: I suggest (based on no solid evidence) that the prohibition on forward references is merely a best-effort attempt ["to catch, at compile time, circular or otherwise malformed initializations"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#d5e12805). For example, you can also forward-reference a variable through a method invocation. So, it catches obviously-wrong code, but just doesn't try too hard to stop you if you are really going to insist you know what you're doing.

Comment: *The use is a simple name in either an instance variable initializer of C or an instance initializer of C...* that **simple name** is very very bothering, I never understood this part of the documentation and the need for it... basically it's not an error because the JLS says so and `javac` conforms to that rule, a questionable rule if you ask me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the following class

```
public class MyClass {
    int a = b;
    int b = 10;
}
```

The [JLS 8.3.3.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3) states in your case :

> Use of instance variables whose declarations appear textually after the use is sometimes restricted
>    - The use is a simple name in either an instance variable initializer of C or an instance initializer of C

Now, using the member `this` allows you to access an instance that is already declared with default values ( `a = 0, b = 0` ) but not yet fully initialized. This is visible if you check the result of:

```
public class MyClass {
    int a = this.b;
    int b = 10;
}
```

You would not get the expected value :

```
new MyClass().a //0
new MyClass().b //10
```

I can't explain why this is legal exactly since this would never give a correct value. We can find some explanation about why the restriction exist :

> The restrictions above are designed to catch, at compile time, circular or otherwise malformed initializations.

But why allowing `this` to works...

---

Knowing that during an initialization of an instance, the following actions occurs :

1. Member declaration
2. Block execution and Field initialization in order
3. Constructor execution

Give some strange behavior:

```
public class MyClass {

    {
        b = 10;
    }
    int a = this.b;
    int b = 5;
    {
        b = 15;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass m = new MyClass();
        System.out.println(m.a); //10
        System.out.println(m.b); //15
    }
}
```

I would limit the initialization in the constructor.